# Problems with gravity and Hebrew

Tags: android, hebrew, gravity

We are writing an application with Hebrew.

When we come to run it on 2 different phones we get different alignment.
Even though we have gravity set to right - one goes to the left.
Both are Samsung and both are 2.3.3.

The locale for both (as given by getDefault()) is "he".

The only difference we have noticed is that in the one that works, when you go into the settings screen the text is right justified (as it should be).
When you go into the one that is bad then also in the settings screen it is justified wrongly.

Anyone else working in Hebrew got any experience in this problem?

Ideas from anyone would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a known problem, with no real solution.

If the text is a single line, set its width to "wrap_content" and align the field itself to the left.

For multiline fields try to center the text (if your designer would allow it...)

Finally, you can do what yNet did - put in the settings "check this if Hebrew is not aligned right" and change the fields gravity in you code accordingly.

In general, I suggest not to force gravity on the field (unless you use the Settings option) - let the system decide the right direction.
(What can we do if Samsung screw up with text direction?!?!?)

Comment: If I don't put in gravity then it will always be to the left.

Comment: Changing the fields within the program is a LOT of work since I would have to go field by field. Is there any way I can "cheat" and use locale? The reason I ask is because when we put gravity as "left" then the one that didn't work now works and the one that worked doesn't. Is using setDefault(locale) and then creating a second set of layouts ok or is that real bad way to go about it?

Comment: As I told you, I had (and still have) the same problem and I didn't find any workaround...
The problem with the gravity is that if you set it to the left, on some devices English will align to the Right (i.e. always do the opposite...).
The opposite direction problem is on specific devices (like Samsung i9000 v2.3.x, if I'm not wrong) and it was fixed on Android4 for those devices.